# TKinter App with SQLite - Pagination Page is not always loading images properly

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

THANK YOU -
First of all I´d like to say thank you to the community because as a newbee it was hard to get my first app to work. But now it does and that's because here I found so much helpful answers!
Mille Grazie.

THE APP -
My app organises my small parts collection in the workshop.
In an SQLite database all Metadata is stored like: Box Numbers, Shelf and Rack Numbers, Descriptions of what is in the Boxes.
All Images are stored in a Folder on the OS.
In the Database I only save the Paths to the Images.

THE PROBLEM -
When I do a Search I get the Results in a Pagination Window displaying only 5 Matches.
You can klick NEXT to see the next 5 Matches.
But sometimes not all Pictures are loaded properly. Some Frames stay blank sometimes.
Then you klick NEXT - and - BACK and then they are there.
I´m sure the Problem is that my Computer can´t load all the images always quick enough.

THE QUESTION -
Is there a way in TKinter to make the Program check if an Image was properly displayed before proceeding with the next one?

This is the desired view with all Images loaded:
[image: This is the desired view with all Images loaded]

But sometimes it looks like this:
[image: But sometimes it looks like this]

Or like this:
[image: Or like this]

Comment: Could this be the problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091

Comment: It is better to provide a [mre] so that we know what the issue is.